# Can't get rid of garbage in a dense city

Tags: simcity-2013

My city has 90k residents. There are two recyclings centers and one garbage dump, all having their maximum number of collecting trucks. There are volunteers from nearby cities as well (at least 32).

Still, there is a large garbage problem in the city. Out of the top of my head, about 2000/4000 garbage is collected, and 4000/12000 recycling materials are collected.

Either the capacity of these buildings to pick up garbage is disappointing, I'm doing something wrong, or I'm suffering from a bug. Which is it?

Comment: Also [see this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qV6PrEjaH8Q) for alleviating traffic problems :)

Comment: @SadlyNot "techniques" links to a SimCity4 question, which is not the same game.

Answer (score 3):

When garbage is collected by visiting volunteers, it is not counted in the summary numbers.

Review the garbage collection dataview.  If there is no garbage in any building, your garbage is collected.  There is no benefit to adding more service vehicles in this situation.

---

Also, with update 7's change to pathfinding for service vehicles, garbage trucks are much more efficient than in the past.  You may find that 3 garages (6 trucks) can pick up all the garbage in a city that size.

Comment: I haven't checked the data map, but I get many town hall protests about the garbage and building popups often say things like "Annoyed the garbage wasn't picked up".

Comment: If you have a true garbage collection problem, the dataview should be the first place you look.

Comment: Yeah you're probably right. I'm pretty new to the game (though I played SimCity 4 a lot) and haven't gotten into the habit of using all the maps yet.

Answer (score 0):

what I've done in the pat is build a dump city/ power where all your garbage goes and your power comes from just build all dumps and cheap power until you get near zero $ exit the city and volunteer all the trucks and all power to your city in need then get rid of your dump in the city you have a problem with. Now you have an unlimited supply of trucks to take all the garbage out of the city and power for the city. This also lowers pollution and frees up space.